External User Presence in Teams via Graph API in 2024
I've noticed something interesting about external user presence in Microsoft Teams, and I'm curious if anyone can shed some light on this.
When I search for external users (not in my organization) in the Teams app, I can often see their presence status - whether they're online, busy, away, etc.
But here's the puzzling part: when I try to get the same information through the Microsoft Graph API using the /presence endpoint, all I get is "PresenceUnknown" for these external users.
I'm wondering:
Is this by design?
Is there a way to get external users' presence via the Graph API that I'm missing?
Is there a way to get external users activity details without having to send them an invitation?
Thanks in advance for any explanations or thoughts!

This is by design behavior, Graph API to get presence does not work for External users. Currently, there is no workaround for this.
